# HTML Jump link - How to create a jump link

Tags: html

I had downloaded one html template for my website and updated with my content. Navigation bar is like home, service, about us, team and contact. When we launch the page, first it will load a slide and that is home and when we click service it will jump to service. But now i want to separate "home" form slide. In the slide there a button "Start Now". When we click it, its jump to services. But now i need separate the home from the welcome slide and when i click start now it should jump to home. I will add a content in home. Its a one page template.

```html
<header id="home">
    <div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/slider/1.jpg)">
          <div class="caption">
            <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">Welcome to <span>Mysite</span></h1>
            <p class="animated fadeInRightBig">Some content</p>
            <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#services">Start now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/2.jpg)">
          <div class="caption">
            <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">SAY HELLOW TO <span>My page</span></h1>
            <p class="animated fadeInRightBig">Some content</p>
            <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#services">Start now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/3.jpg)">
          <div class="caption">
            <h1 class="animated fadeInLeftBig">We are <span>Creative</span></h1>
      
            <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="#services">Start now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left-control" href="#home-slider" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right-control" href="#home-slider" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      <a id="tohash" href="#services"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

    </div><!--/#home-slider-->
    <div class="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <h1><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
          </a>                    
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                 
            <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Service</a></li> 
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>       
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/#main-nav-->
  </header><!--/#home-->
  <section id="services">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-7 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
      <div class="text-right our-services">
  <div class="text-center service-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="text-right service-info">
              <h3><b><u>Service Content</b></h3></div>
     </div>
     </div>
       <div class="col-md-8 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
    <img  src="images/content/service-1.jpg" alt="service1" style="width:140%;height:50%;">
          </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <div class="text-right our-services">
   <div class="text-center service-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="450ms">
            <div class="text-right service-info">
             <h3><b><u>Service Content</u></b></h3>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="450ms">
    <img src="images/content/service-2.jpg" alt="service1" style="width:140%;height:50%;">
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="550ms">
    <div class="text-right our-services">
            <div class="text-center service-icon">
              <i class="fa fa-life-bouy"></i>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="550ms">
            <div class="text-center service-info">
              <h3><b><u>Service Content</u></b></h3>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-9 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="550ms">
    <img  src="images/content/service-3.jpg" alt="service1" style="width:140%;height:50%;">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section><!--/#services-->
```

I tried modifying it but its not happening. I need some one to help me in this. Here is my html code.

Comment: You need to provide minimal code. see [this](/help/mcve) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherevr you want to redirect just pass the id of that section in the href of the clicked link like below.

```
href="#services"   Link with this value navigate user to services section

href="#Home" Link with this value navigate user to home section
```

You can update your html based on requirement.

Comment: Hope  this helps, Please mark it as an answer if this is as per requirement.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote here?  People should give the reason for the downvote.